# Excel: Find most frequent occurring value in a range?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a column on sheet 1 like so:

```
Column D
    Dog
    Dog
    Dog
    Dog
    Cat
    Cat
    Cat
    Hamster
    Frog
    Frog
```

On sheet 2, i want to list the top 10 most frequent occurring words in chronological order

```
Dog .  <---Most Frequent
Cat .  <---Second Frequent
Frog . <--Third
etc.
```

I am trying to use index, mode and match like so:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MODE(MATCH(Sheet1!D:D,Sheet1!D:D,0)))
```

This produces an N/A error

But if i add ranges to my column reference like so:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!D1:D10,MODE(MATCH(Sheet1!D1:D10,Sheet1!D1:D10,0)))
```

Then it works.

Problem is data is going to be added to columnn D and i need it to look up the entire column D.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Used named ranges to get the data range. Several ways to do this, counta , isblank etc. Then stick the named range in the formula instead of D1:D10

Comment: Blank values are your issue that is causing the error.  If you even try an explicit range, but with one cell that is blank you will get the same error.  Follow @MacroMarc ideas and you should get there.

Comment: You could just use a pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

If we use a helper column we can completely eliminate the need for array formulas.  In **E1** enter `1` and in **E2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,D2)>0,"",1+MAX($E$1:E1))
```

and copy down as far as column **D**. *(as items are added to column **D**, pull the column **E** formula down as well)*

Finally in **F1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),E:E,0)),"")
```

and copy down.  In **G1** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(D:D,F1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

NOTE:

*The little frequency table in columns **F** and **G** is "sort-able".*