# Getting the 10 Top most frequent names in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling to come up with a program capable of extracting the 10 most frequent names appearing in a column and storing them into an array for further use.

Comment: I don't see any code. Post what you've come up with so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904207/excel-find-most-frequent-occurring-value-in-a-range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gather the column's values into an array to speed processing. Transfer to a dictionary's keys with the frequency as each key's item. The worksheet's Large can easily find the 10th largest frequency. Remove anything that has a lower frequency.

```
Option Explicit

Sub gfdrew()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arr As Variant, k As Variant, dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With Worksheets("sheet6")
        arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
    End With

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        dict.Item(arr(i, 1)) = dict.Item(arr(i, 1)) + 1
    Next i

    j = Application.Large(dict.items, Application.Min(10, dict.Count))

    For Each k In dict.keys
        If dict.Item(k) < j Then dict.Remove (k)
    Next k

    arr = dict.keys

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice method. Why use Application.Min over WorksheetFunction please?

Comment: I use Application for all worksheet functions. Either they work exactly the same or you gain added benefits such as error control on a lookup.

Comment: Great solution! Helped me a lot, never knew you could scripting dictionary this way. Appreciate it a lot!