# VBA to find the largest occurring word in the column and its count

Tags: excel, vba

In column "L" I have 9 words occurring multiple times, in a total of 54 rows.

**My question is**:

I need as output the word that occurred the maximum number of times and the count of occurrences as well. Since I can't attach the file I have provided a screenshot of the excel:

[image]

**According to the screenshot:**

- Output1 will be HD
- Output2 will be 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this array formula with CSE,

```
=index(l2:index(l:l, match("zzz", l:l)), mode(match(l2:index(l:l, match("zzz", l:l)), l2:index(l:l, match("zzz", l:l)), 0)))
```

If you stll want VBA look at [Excel VBA: Getting the 10 Top most frequent name in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214927/excel-vba-getting-the-10-top-most-frequent-name-in-a-column/52216726)

Comment: You made my day... I got the answer correct :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get the count of the most common word, I would use Frequency:

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(L2:L100<>"",MATCH(L2:L100,L2:L100,0),""),ROW(L2:L100)-1))
```

based on [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-in-a-range) and [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273)

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note that it is good practice to use index and match to establish the range dynamically as @Jeeped has done. I have been a little lazy and assumed that you can put a maximum on the range (like 100 rows).

Comment: Thanks your are a genius.. I got the count :)